# Convergence in distribution of $n^{-1}X_n$, where $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for every $n\in\Bbb{N} $

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n\sim\text{U}(\{1,\dots,n\}),\ \forall n\in\Bbb{N} $. I now want to show that $n^{-1}X_n$ converges in distribution for $n\to \infty$. I seem to however make a mistake along the way, therefore I would really appreciate it if someone could point out the flaw in my argument. Thanks!

Let $\varphi_{X_n}$ be the characteristic equation of $X_n$. We obtain for $n^{-1}X_n$:
$\varphi_{n^{-1}X_n}(t)=\Bbb{E}[e^{it\frac{X_n}{n}}]=\sum^n_{k=1}e^{it\frac{k}{n}}P(X_n=k),\quad$ as $X_n$ is uniformly distributed, it follows that $P(X_n=k)=\frac{1}{n}$
$\qquad \quad \;\: = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}(e^{\frac{it}{n}})^k=\frac{e^{it/n}(1-e^{it})}{n(1-e^{it/n})} $ by use of the formula for geometric series.
By calculating the limit of this expression for $n\to \infty$ we obtain:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{n^{-1}X_n}(t)=\frac{1-e^{it}}{-it}$$The characteristic equation of continuous, on $(a,b)$ uniformly distributed, random variables is the following: $$\varphi_{\text{U}(a,b)}(t)=\frac{e^{itb}-e^{ita}}{it(b-a)}$$ If we chose $(a,b)=(1,0)$ the above calculated limit would equal this characteristic equation, however this doesn't make sense, as of course $b$ must be larger than $a$.

Comment: I would try proving this without characteristic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually
$$
\frac{1-e^{it}}{-it}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}
$$
so you can choose $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Oops, I feel like I should have gotten that haha. Thanks!